# GeoDjango PointField | JSON serializer | coordinates

Tags: json, django, coordinates, postgis, geodjango

So I have this problem in my app.

When I try to create user that have attribute "location" that is a GeoDjango PointField, only value set as 'default' is saved... When I send request with postman, that 'location field' is ignored.

In installed apps:
...
djangorestframework-gis,
django.contrib.gis
...

Postgis is installed and database is created with postgis extension.

This is part of models.py User object

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    location = models.PointField(geography=True, spatial_index=True,default=Point(0.0, 0.0, srid=4326))
    ...
```

This is what I tried as JSON:

```
{
"location": "POINT(-120.18444970926208 50.65664762026928)"
}
```

---

```
{
 "location": {
     "type":"Point",
     "coordinates": "[34.000, 21.000]"
     }
}
```

---

```
{
 "location": {
     "type":"Point",
     "coordinates": {
         "lng":"21.000",
         "lat":"32.000"
     }
 }
  }
```

---

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""
Serializer for user object
"""
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = '__all__'


def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
        last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
        address=validated_data['address'],
    )
    # user.location = validated_data['location']
    user.username = validated_data['username']
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user


class UpgradeUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

user = UserSerializer(required=True)

class Meta:
    model = UpgradeUser
    fields = ('user',
              'upgrade_name',
              'oib',
              'upgrade_address',
              'legal_representative',
              'gsm',
              'marketplace_seller',
              'weekend_delivery'
              )

def create(self, validated_data):

    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')

    user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(),     validated_data=user_data)
    user.is_upgrade = True
    user.save()

    upgrade_user = UpgradeUser.objects.create(
        user=user, **validated_data
    )

    upgrade_user.save()
    return upgrade_user
```

In the DB,location fields is populated with default coordinates that`s are 0.0, 0.0.
DB GeoHash -->  0101000020E610000000000000000000000000000000000000

I do not know what I am doing wrong and that is frustrating....
I think that my JSON is wrong and that`s way serializer save default.

As you can see my location field on serializer is commented. So do I need to make Serializer only for location field and than embed it in UserSerializer?

---

---

### SOLUTION: after spending 20 days on this problem.

1. for models use django gis models

   `from django.contrib.gis.db import models`
2. Use that models.PointField()

   `location = models.PointField(geography=True, srid=4326)`
3. Need to install DRF GIS and use this serializer

   `from rest_framework_gis.serializers import GeoModelSerializer`
4. When you subclass serializer use:

   `geo_field = 'point'`

in `class Meta:` as attribute.

and then when you POST json in format that guys specified in comments:

```
{ "location": { "type":"Point", "coordinates": "[34.000, 21.000]" }}
```

everything have to work.

Comment: Without having the full code (e.g. the serializer or the form) it is very hard to answer. So here are some guesses and try out recommendations:

The normal GeoJson format looks like this (Coordinates are not a string): 
{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -13799164.078734191134572, 6303756.219785275869071 ]} 

Otherwise try to remove the default and check what error you get when sending the request

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply. I updated question with serializers. I have two serializer, one is NormalUser and other is UpgradedUser *OneOnOneField, i didnt use proxy model because I need to add additional fields on extended user.), So as i said in updated version, do I need to write serializer just for location field so I can save geohash into Postgis DB?

Comment: Error is {
    "user": {
        "location": [
            "Unable to convert to python object: Invalid geometry pointer returned from \"OGR_G_CreateGeometryFromJson\"."
        ]
    }
}

Comment: { "location": { "type":"Point", "coordinates": "[34.000, 21.000]" }}, coordinates is an array, not a string, try { "coordinates": [34.000, 21.000] }

Comment: I solved it. Plan to write full description for others if they find themself in the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting on this issue, here is the doc for how to handle this.

https://github.com/openwisp/django-rest-framework-gis?tab=readme-ov-file#serializers

For instance, I needed to do this for making it works:

"
Note: For ver>=0.9.3: The DRF model serializer will give the same output as above, if;

- rest_framework_gis is set in settings.INSTALLED_APPS or
- **the field in the serializer is set explicitly as GeometryField.**"